# Programmatically added constraints are not always working

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, constraints, indentation

I am programmatically adding these constraints on a cell in order to indent in for sub tabs. Most of the time it works, however, as the screenshot shows, it doesn't always work. The code below shows the constraints. [image]

```
let views: [String:Any] = ["parent": self, "view": self.borderView, "subview": self.backView, "button1": self.actionButton, "label": self.name, "button2": self.nextButton]
    let margin1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-\(margin*level+8)-[subview]-8-|",
        options: .alignAllCenterY,
        metrics: nil,
        views: views)

    let margin2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-\(margin*level+8)-[view]-8-|",
        options: .alignAllCenterY,
        metrics: nil,
        views: views)

    let margin3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-8-[button1]-[label]-[button2]-8-|",
                                                 options: .alignAllCenterY,
                                                 metrics: nil,
                                                 views: views)

    self.addConstraints(margin1)
    self.addConstraints(margin2)
    self.addConstraints(margin3)

    self.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    self.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
    self.updateConstraints()
```

I am using autolayout, and these cells are in their own xib file. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Is there more than one type of cell in the table?

Comment: @D.Greg No, there is not. I am just adjusting the colors, etc, based on the level of the sub cell.

Comment: What's wrong with it now? Is that that its distance to the alarm is more than the others? (It's a bit hard to understand how you expect it to look like, since some of your cells have `+/-` and some of your cells are indented, and also this issue for the cell...

Comment: @linuxer Can you be more specific about when it happens. Is it on scroll into view or some other animation?

Comment: @D.Greg Sorry, I wasn't clear on what is wrong. So in this current view all the light green cells should be indented slightly just like the very top light green cell. As you can see the 2nd and 5th cell are all the way to the left. If you hide and show the cells it changes on which ones indent and which ones indent and which ones don't.

Comment: @linuxer I understand that, but I'd like to know when you're seeing the issue.

Comment: @D.Greg When the tableview initially loads it just has the dark green cells. When you click on the cell it loads the sub cells. Sometimes they are all indented correctly. Other times just one is not indented correctly, and yet other times more. There's no specific pattern that I see. Does that make sense? It will also change if I click on the parent cell to hide the subcells and then click again to show the subcells again

Comment: @linuxer I had a similar problem causing by `dequeReuseableCell` It was sometime last year. If I find the project, I'll post the solution here. In the meantime, look for problems related to `dequeReusableCell`

Comment: @D.Greg Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can just check in `cellForRowAt` whether the background of the cell is light green, (plus it is unselected) and activate the appropriate constraints.

Comment: @PranavKasetti I do this in a way already. I am just checking for the level of the node (0,1,2) I then multiply the margin by the level. (i.e. 15*level) It works most of the time, but not all of the time

Comment: I'd check you are replacing your dequeued constraints by deactivation of all constraints prior to resetting the constraints.

Comment: As has been said by @D.Greg, the problem is with the `dequeueReusableCell` function.

Comment: Adding this line to prepareForReuse seems to have solved it. self.removeConstraints(self.constraints)

Comment: @linuxer great!